# How can I upload .rvt (revit) files to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, upload, revit-api, file-type

I have a client that wants to allow his users to download a .rvt (revit) file from his website. I need to find a way to be able to upload this filetype to Wordpress.

I added the following to my functions.php and it doesn't work:

```
/* ALLOW FILE TYPES */
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['rvt'] = 'application/octet-stream';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

I also installed WP Forms' "File Upload Type" plugin. They didn't have Revit files listed so I added a custom one but it also doesn't work (I am using this plugin to allow for .dwg files).
You can see what I did here:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can allow for this filetype would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `'application/rvt'` and `'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'`. Maybe these will work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried those but they don't work. I found these pages that mention the MIME type: 

http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/Ext:rvt
https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/ (search REVIT)

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type 'application/octet-stream' may not be the best choice for Revit files. You should use 'application/vnd.autodesk.autocad' as the correct MIME type for .rvt files.

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['rvt'] = 'application/vnd.autodesk.autocad';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

Also, ensure that your server also allows the upload and storage of .rvt files. Some servers might have restrictions that prevent certain file types from being uploaded.

After making these adjustments, users should be able to upload .rvt files through your website.